# google app engine: how can client code detect if user is logged in or not?

Tags: google-app-engine

While developing a Google App Engine app, how can client code (i.e., javascript) detect if a user is logged in or not? Note I am referring to detection on the client (not server).

Comment: are you using java or python?

Comment: @adithya it java or pythorn refers to the back end, it doesn't really matters what you use in order to determine if the user is logged in server side. I am using gae-sessions and I am passing the user as a variable suggested in the first answer.

Comment: It would be nice, so I can show logout button without creating a different version of public pages, so that they can just be cached regardless of the login status.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For something like this, you really need a custom solution.
The [Users API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/) will tell you what you need to know on the server-side, but it's up to you to send this information to the Javascript on the client-side.
I usually add a snippet to the template. Something like:

```
<script>var username="{{ user.username }}";</script>
```

If the username variable is an empty string, the user is not logged in, otherwise, you have their username ready to go. Of course you can always just use a boolean value, but this supports a bit more functionality if you need it later.

**EDIT**: I don't know if this is a recommended way to do it, but there's another way I've tried since posting this answer. Simply serve your main page as normal, but add a script tag:

```
<script src="/myapi/userinfo"></script>
```

Then create a `/myapi/userinfo` endpoint which responds with `var user = {/* User Stuff */};` if the user is logged in, and `var user = null;` if not.

The main advantage to this is your pages can be cached and served without the need to re-render them for each user. However, this means that you need some JavaScript that will customize the page once it's on the client (show their username, logout button, etc).

Comment: Yeah. just create a javascript to validate whether user still login.

Comment: But this requires interaction from the server, which invalidates the cache.

Comment: I am using the similar method, however, the problem is the possibility of javascript injection over Chrome Developer Tool.  A user can change the content of username variable then can access the account. Is this concern is reasonable?

Comment: Changing the username variable shouldn't enable the javascript to access anything it couldn't before.

If some user had the username value `Emir` and you change it to `Elif` it doesn't change anything else. The user still has `Emir`'s cookie, so they interact with `Emir`'s account.

The only effect it has is on what the client-side javascript renders to the browser.